# Как считать общую стоимость, когда цена единицы меняется шагами?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Пользователь вводит количество писем, и получает общую стоимость рассылки. Есть массив количеств писем `post` и массив цен за отправку одного письма из этих диапазонов `prescurant`

```
var post       = [1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 20000];
var prescurant = [0,    0.08, 0.07, 0.06,  0.05, 0.04];
```

- за первые 1000 писем пользователь отдаст по 0 руб.;
- за письма с 1001 по 3000-е он отдаст по 0.08 руб. за письмо;
- с 3001 до 5000 – по 0.07 руб.;
- и т.д.
- каждое письмо свыше 20000 стоит по 0.04 рубля.

Как рассчитать общую стоимость, когда цена единицы меняется шагами и заданы эти пороги?

---

Пытался так:

```
var val=2000//введеные пользователем кол-во писем
for(i=0;i<post.length;i++){
   for(j=0;j<prescurant.length;j++){
       otv=(post[i]-post[i+1])*prescurant[j]
   }
}
$("#otv").html(otv)
```

Comment: @Sergiks выше наработки указал,немогу решить,непонимаю как

Comment: Двигаться по массиву количеств и вычитать из введённого числа встреченные до тех пор, пока остаток не станет меньше или равен 0. А к сумме стоимости прибавлять соотв. цены умноженные на кол-во очередного шага.

Comment: @Sergiks,напишите пожалуйста

Comment: Зачем вы удалили из исправленного вопроса пояснения, без которых не понятно, что имеется в виду? Цифры сами потом поменяете.

Comment: @AnisimovIva так и не понимаю условия задачи, особенно   *за следующие 2000*,  вы бы привели расчёты для примера за 3000 и 3001, за 20000 и 20001, чтоб всем было понятно

Comment: @рони как я понял, число писем накапливается – за месяц и сбрасывается, или бессрочно, только накапливается. И по мере изменения счётчика, каждое письмо тарифицируется по вот этим правилам. Первая 1000 бесплатно. С 1001-го письма уже за 0.08. И до 3000-го. 3001-е уже будет всего за 0.07

Comment: @Sergiks так почему тс был против что 2000 писем стоят 80 рублей `до 1000 * 0 + 1000 *0.08 = 80 – рони` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как надо на такие вопросы отвечать

```
var post=[1000,3000,5000,10000,20000],prescurant=[0,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.04],val=5001;
for(var i=0,otv=0;val>0;otv+=prescurant[i]*(val>(i?(post[i]-post[i-1]):post[i])?i?(post[i]-post[i-1]):post[i]:val),val-=i?(post[i]-post[i-1]):post[i],i++);
console.log(otv);
```

Comment: Как жестоко! : ) Это же бесполезно другим читателям с похожими вопросами.

Comment: @Sergiks Вопрос из серии сделайте за меня. К тому же он так сформулирован, что вряд ли его найдет кто-нибудь, кому нужно нечто подобное.

Comment: тогда стоит помочь ТС переформулировать вопрос или сделать это за него. Задача-то довольно типичная, кому-то ещё понадобится шагать по интервалам.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var post=[1000,3000,5000,10000,20000];
var cost=[0,0.08,0.07,0.06,0.05,0.04];
function checkPrice() {
  var n = parseInt( $('#in-letters').val(), 10)
    ,step = 0
    ,priced = 0
    ,done = 0
    ,sum = 0
  ;
  if( !n) return;
  while(step < post.length) {
    priced = n > post[step] ? post[step] - done : n - done;
    sum += cost[step] * priced;
    done += priced;
    if( done == n) break;
    step++;
  }
  if( done < n) sum += cost[step] * (n - done); // over 20k
  $("#out").html(sum);
}
$('#btn').on('click', checkPrice);
```

```html
<link href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="in-letters">Кол-во писем</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="in-letters" placeholder="2500">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default">Сколько стоит?</button>
  <div id="out"></div>
</div>
```